# How to use parameterized base class constructor downstream of virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual-inheritance

I have a class structure that looks like the following:

```
  O
  |
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
  |
  E
```

And the constructors work as follows (specific code not included for brevity, but I can flesh this out more if necessary):

```
class O {
  protected:
    O(const string &str) {
      //Does stuff with str
    };
}

class A : public O {
  protected:
    A(const string &str) : O(str) { };
}

class B : public virtual A {
  protected:
    B(const string &str) : A(str) { };
}

class C : public virtual A {
  protected:
    C(const string &str) : A(str) { };
}

class D : public B, public C {
  protected:
    D(const string &str) : B(str), C(str) { };
}

class E : public D {
  public:
    E(const string &str) : D(str) { };
}
```

Classes O, A, B, C, and D  are supposed to be part of a library with class D being the base class for any classes I make later (such as E).  The only purpose of D is to simplify inheritance for classes like E.  My problem is that the constructor of E calls the default constructor of A unless I explicitly call A's parameterized constructor, which defeats the purpose of D.

This inheritance structure is best for my application because classes C & D are being used to specialize an infrastructure created by A & B.  C contains additional methods for A.

Is there a way I can make D handle the call to A's parameterized constructor?  Ideally, I would like an initialization of E to call the constructors A, B, C, D, E in that order.  The string parameter is very important to classes upstream of O, and the constructors B and C need to run specific functions.

Comment: Does `A` need a default constructor?

Comment: That class structure is never a good thing.

Comment: @aschepler - A does not need a default constructor except for allowing construction of E without explicitly calling A's string constructor.

Comment: @erip - I agree that this is not ideal, but considering the broader class structure encompassing this section, this was the simplest layout without creating duplicate classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Virtual base classes must *always* be constructed by the most derived class. It cannot work any other way. All you can do is not permit A to be default constructible and have the compiler help you out, or refactor your code to not use diamond inheritance in the first place.

Comment: Not the answer I really wanted, but what I was expecting.  Thanks!